# Send shell variable to slack notification in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, slack

I have a shell script which does the deployment. There is a variable set in my shell script and I want to pass that variable in slack notification custom message, but its not working as expected.

I have used envInject plugin to set the shell variable as environment variable and its not working as expected

```
${CRQ} is completed in staging. Please validate
Console url is  : ${BUILD_URL}console
```

staging_daily_dose - #114 Failure after 4.4 sec (Open)

````
Console url is  : https://jenkins-host/job/staging_daily_dose/114/console``` 

I want ${CRQ} with the actual value. Can someone help me with the best approach
````

Answer (score 1):

From various posts it is clear that to add an environment variable that can be used by Slack Notification Plugin needs to be inserted using Inject Environment Variable, So

1. In The Build step create a properties file and write the required variables, and use the file in the Inject Environment Variables Plugin

[image]

2. Next use the variable in the Slack Notification Plugin
   [image]

This will result in a slack message like below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the variables as `$VARIABLE` along with the messages in the `Post-build Actions -> Slack Notifications -> Include Custom Message` section as  shown in the image below.

Slack notification configuration:

[image]